# Inconsistent behavior in Ruby gsub replacement?

Tags: ruby, regex, gsub

The two gsub's yield different outcomes. Can anybody explain why?

Code is also available at https://gist.github.com/franklsf95/6c0f8938f28706b5644d.

```
    ver = 9999
    str = "\t<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>\n\t<string>en</string>\n\t<key>CFBundleVersion</key>\n\t<string>0.1.190</string>\n\t<key>AppID</key>\n\t<string>000000000000000</string>"
    puts str.gsub /(CFBundleVersion<\/key>\n\t.*\.).*(<\/string>)/, "#{$1}#{ver}#{$2}"
    puts '--------'
    puts str.gsub /(CFBundleVersion<\/key>\n\t.*\.).*(<\/string>)/, "#{$1}#{ver}#{$2}"
```

My ruby version is `ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-darwin13.0]` (MRI). On my machine, the outcome is:

```
<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
<string>en</string>
<key>9999
<key>AppID</key>
<string>000000000000000</string>
--------
<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
<string>en</string>
<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>0.1.9999</string>
<key>AppID</key>
<string>000000000000000</string>
```

The second one is the desired effect, but the first one is wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It has to do with timing and how ruby regexes work.

`gsub` sets `$1` and `$2`, but not until after it completes.  So when you run the first time through, they're blank.  When you run the second time, they were set by the previous `gsub`.  If you want to do regex captures in place, you need `\1` and `\2`, like this:

```
puts str.gsub /(CFBundleVersion<\/key>\n\t.*\.).*(<\/string>)/, '\1' + ver.to_s + '\2'
```

Comment: That's great to know, +1 :)

Comment: You could also use the block form of `gsub`: `str.gsub(/(CFBundleVersion<\/key>\n\t.*\.).*(<\/string>)/) {"#{$1}#{ver}#{$2}"}`

Comment: Can you explain more explicitly the difference between '\1' and "$1"? Thanks!

Comment: My understanding is that when you pass in the args to gsub, $1 and $2 are evaluated before the call to gsub is executed and then passed as arguments to gsub.  \1 and \2 don't have any special meaning to ruby per se, but gsub recognizes them and handles them the same way perl would handle $1 and $2 in a similar scenario.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the block form of gsub(), your code will work correctly:

```
ver = 9999

str = "\t<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>\n\t<string>en</string>\n\t<key>CFBundleVersion</key>\n\t<string>0.1.190</string>\n\t<key>AppID</key>\n\t<string>000000000000000</string>"

puts str.gsub(/(CFBundleVersion<\/key>\n\t.*\.).*(<\/string>)/) {|match|
  "#{$1}#{ver}#{$2}"
}

puts '-' * 20

puts str.gsub(/(CFBundleVersion<\/key>\n\t.*\.).*(<\/string>)/) {|match|
  "#{$1}#{ver}#{$2}"
}

--output:--
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>0.1.9999</string>
    <key>AppID</key>
    <string>000000000000000</string>
--------------------
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>0.1.9999</string>
    <key>AppID</key>
    <string>000000000000000</string>
```

The docs describe this behavior:

> If replacement is a String,
>   ...
>   However, within replacement the special match variables, such as $&,
>   will not refer to the current match.
>
> ...
>
> In the block form, the current match string is passed in as a
>   parameter, and variables such as $1, $2, $`, $&, and $' will be set
>   appropriately. The value returned by the block will be substituted for
>   the match on each call.

Comment: Is it because the regex matching is done before the block is executed, but not done when the arguments are passed to gsub in the non-block form?

Comment: ^ It seems to be the case.